# Bind J2SE Endpoint to HTTPS

Tags: java, web-services, restful-authentication

I created a basic REST service that works when it is invoked over a http connection. But when I try to add SSL on top I have some problems.

This is the code for the server creation:

```
 private HttpContext getHttpContext() {
  HttpsServer server = null;
  try {
   server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 443), 5);

   server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(SecureChatSslContextFactory.getServerContext()) {

    public void configure(HttpsParameters params) {
     SSLContext context = getSSLContext();

     // get the default parameters
     SSLParameters sslparams = context.getDefaultSSLParameters();
     params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
    }
   });

   server.start();

   return server.createContext("/customerservice/customer");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
 } 
    Endpoint e = Endpoint.create(HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING, new RestSourcePayloadProvider()); 
    e.publish(getHttpContext());
```

The class `RestSourcePayloadProvide`r has the public method invoke, but it never gets called. I suppose that the reason for this behaviour is that the binding for the endpoint is `HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING`, and not HTTPS. But I didn't manage to find a way to bind to https.

If I run the test client or the browser on [link text](https://localhost:443/customerservice/customer) I get the same answer:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>   No handler for context

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem. I was not creating a handler for the incoming requests. 
I was supposed to use

```
return server.createContext("/customerservice/customer", new HttpHandler(...));
```

instead of

```
return server.createContext("/customerservice/customer");
```

It looks like the interface `Endpoint` is implemented by the `EndpointImpl`class in Apache's CFX. When calling `publish(address)`, the method called in `EndpointImpl` creates a `ServerImpl` that will be the service server. If I call `publish(server context)`, nothing happens because `EndpointImpl` doesn't override that method also.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use the CFX's EndpointImpl and SSL try this:
[link text](http://aruld.info/programming-ssl-for-jetty-based-cxf-services/)

It uses the Jetty Server package to create the working server and publish it to the endpoint.