# SOAP message on Java SE

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

Using JAX-WS on Java SE 7.

The guides on Soap Handlers seem to assume a Java EE server. Is this essential for SOAP handlers or can they also work in Java SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement web services in Java SE.

You just need to start up an Endpoint and publish it.

[This](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/vivekp/archive/2006/12/webservices_in.html) is a simple example.

Java EE and servlet containers handle the publishing part for you. Outside of that, they're pretty much the same thing and handled the same way.

Answer (score -2):

A web service gets deployed either on a Servlet container (like Tomcat) or any Java EE application server (like JBoss AS, WebLogic etc).

So Java SE is not enough for deploying your web service.

Comment: Implementing a client not a service I would like to know if I may use soap handlers. Thanks

Comment: Client implementation you can do in pure Java so J2SE is enough.

Comment: Your answer is plain wrong. J2SE provides full support for both web service clients AND web service implementation. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001739/compile-ws-client-in-java-1-5-missing-webservice-like-annotations/13005434#13005434) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860588/java-web-service-without-a-web-application-server/12870543#12870543)

Comment: @kolossus pls check my answer carefully. I am talking about "web service deployment" and not implementation. In fact i have also mentioned in my comment that J2SE is enough for writing client.

Comment: Webs service deployment if I'm not mistaken means that you're **running** a web service no? So yes, you can deploy a webservice on J2SE using the [endpoint API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4735116).